# I want to display only one item at a time in checkboxlist n provide scroll bar when we click on checkboxlist for multiselection

Tags: asp.net

i want a checklistbox as a dropdownlist with checkbox inside.
means it must provide scroll bars in checkboxlist n show 1 item at first.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your CheckBoxList in a `<div>`.

CSS:

```
#wrapper{ border:solid 1px #aaa; height:20px; width:300px; overflow:auto;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkBoxes" runat="server" ></asp:CheckBoxList>
</div>
```

Then use javascript to change the styling (CSS) of the `<div>` on the onclick event.

Here's an implementation example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/MultiSelect.aspx